# How do I calculate the probability of obtaining a particular score on a Social Studies quiz?

Tags: probability

I recently took a Social Studies quiz in which I had to label the twenty-six eastern United States on a map. I know for certain that I got at least half of them correct. How would I calculate the probability of obtaining a particular score based on the probability of getting a particular number of the remaining states correct?

I'm not sure whether or not the number of outcomes possible factors into the calculation. I know that the number of outcomes possible for thirteen states is $13!$. I know not how to calculate the probability of getting a particular number of states correct. Using my expertise in mathematics, I know that the probability of getting one or all of the states correct is $\dfrac1{13}$ and $\dfrac1{13^{13}}$. Given those two statements, the probability of getting one correct is $\dfrac1{13}$, and the probability of getting correct $n$ states is $\dfrac1{13^n}$.

Am I correct? I think not. The above calculation, *as far as I can tell*, accounts not for the probability of getting only the thirteen certain states correct and none of the remaining thirteen. If the calculation indeed accounts not for the probability of getting no more correct, how would one incorporate said probability into the calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you knew the first half, and put the last $13$ labels in at random (i.e. you knew the names of these state capitals and the names of the last $13$ states but not which went where) then there are $13!=6227020800$ possible patterns and the probability of all correct is $\dfrac{1}{13!}$.

For other possible numbers of correct labels, you are looking at [rencontres numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers), which you can calculate with recursion.  The probability of $n\lt 13$ correct is in fact $$\frac{\displaystyle{13 \choose n}\left[\frac{(13-n)!}{e}\right]}{13!}$$   where $[x]$ means rounding to the nearest integer.  These give:

```
 n  13! * prob   probability (rounded)
 0  2290792932   0.36787944116 
 1  2290792933   0.36787944132 
 2  1145396460   0.18393971962 
 3   381798846   0.06131324405 
 4    95449640   0.01532829953 
 5    19090071   0.00306568287 
 6     3181464   0.00051091270 
 7      454740   0.00007302690 
 8       56628   0.00000909392 
 9        6435   0.00000103340 
10         572   0.00000009186 
11          78   0.00000001253 
12           0   0   
13           1   0.00000000016
```

Your expected number correct are the the original known $13$ cases plus $1$ of the unknown ones.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you. P.S. I now realize that my original calculations are incorrect, as one is removing the labels from the query rather than replacing them after being picked. Perhaps I got confused because I was very sleep-deprived at the time of creating the question. Regardless, thank you.